# How to add elements in list in for loop? My output is [1,1,1] instead of [1,4,5]

Tags: python

I have a list. I want to find indices of an string in this list. In my code (given below), I get `[1,1,1]` as output instead of `[1,4,5]`. What am I doing wrong?

```
def search_for_string(lists,str1):
    list2=[]
    for c in lists:
        if (c==str1):
           j=0
           i=lists.index(c)
           list2.insert(j,i)
           j=j+1
        else:
           continue
    return(list2)
#print: [1, 4, 5]
sample_list = ["artichoke", "turnip", "tomato", "potato", "turnip", "turnip", "artichoke"]
print(search_for_string(sample_list, "turnip"))
```

Comment: A good [mcve] would be *the shortest possible thing* that reproduces the issue -- thus, simple enough to make it clear why `[1,4,5]` is actually the correct/desirable answer. (And if you can figure out which operation inside the function is the one that returns the undesirable answer, eliminating the rest of the function and just asking a question about that one operation would be even better).

Comment: Also, some english to help explain your question goes a long way. Just looking at a block of code rarely tells us what the problem is

Comment: Frankly, this doesn't look like a problem with "add[ing] elements in a list in a for loop", but like a problem with how you *calculate* the values you want to add. Someone else with problems "add[ing] elements [to a] list in [a] for loop" is unlikely to be helped by even a correct answer to this question.

Comment: `However, if the same element is present more than once, index() method returns its smallest/first position` [python list.index](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version does not work because index always get the first match. And this code is way cleaner and shorter:

```
def search_for_string(lists,str1):
    list2=[]
    for index, value in enumerate(lists):
        if value==str1:
           lists[index] = 'xxxxx'
           list2.append(index)
    return list2

sample_list = ["artichoke", "turnip", "tomato", "potato", "turnip", "turnip", "artichoke"]
print(search_for_string(sample_list, "turnip"))
```

**Output :**

```
C:\Users\Documents>py test.py
[1, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want in a evry simple way!

```
def search_for_string(lists,str1):

    list2=[]
    counter = 0

    for counter in range(len(lists)):

        if(lists[counter] == str1):
            list2.append(counter)

    return(list2)

sample_list = ["artichoke", "turnip", "tomato", "potato", "turnip", "turnip", "artichoke"]
print(search_for_string(sample_list, "turnip"))
```

It was mainly a logic issue. By controling the list's indexes with `counter` it's much easier to compare and store values.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def foo(l,st):
...     el  =  []
...     for i,j in enumerate(l):
...         if j == st:
...             l[i] = 0
...             el.append(i)
...     return el
... 
>>> example = ["artichoke", "turnip", "tomato", "potato", "turnip", "turnip", 
"artichoke"]
>>> foo(example, 'turnip')
[1, 4, 5]
```

I just placed 0 everywhere at the intended string's place and one by one took the index number.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following codes:

**Code1:**

```
sample_list = ["artichoke", "turnip", "tomato", "potato", "turnip", "turnip", "artichoke"]

def search_for_string(lists,str1):
    list2= []
    for i in range(len(lists)):
        if lists[i]==str1: list2+=[i]
    return list2
```

Or, an even shorter version of the above code:

**Code2:**

```
sample_list = ["artichoke", "turnip", "tomato", "potato", "turnip", "turnip", "artichoke"]

def search_for_string(lists,str1):
    return [i for i in range(len(lists)) if lists[i]==str1 ]
```

Both of the above codes give you the desired output:

```
search_for_string(sample_list,"turnip")
>>> [1, 4, 5]
```

**Code2** is **slightly faster** than Code1.